# Knockout: passing the current object to a method through a custom element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, custom-element

I have a custom html element (a button) which I am passing a method to. This is then executed by the knockout binding in the custom element. The problem is, I need access to the current object in the array, when selected. I have achieved this like so:

```
ko.components.register('custom-element', {
    viewModel: function(params) {

      this.nestedMethod = function (){
        //this line feels dirty
        var parameter = ko.contextFor(arguments[1].target).$parent;
        params.method(parameter);
      }
    }, 
    template:
    '<button data-bind="click: nestedMethod">remove item</button>'
});
```

This feels very hacky and potentially prone to breaking. Is there a nicer way of achieving this? Here is a link to a working example:

http://liveweave.com/w0L5w5

Comment: Build a component with all that you need... Not only button. It will be easier  (i guess) to maintain and would be less hacky (anyway, you are using Client Arrays, try to protect them it's difficult). Don't use global arrays (just use it on their private scope)

Answer (score 1):

Since Knockout components are meant to be reusable across pages and view-models, they should not rely on view-models other than the component's own view-model.

However, you can access your desired data by passing the current `bindingContext` as part of the `params` object.

For example (in your HTML):

```
<custom-element params="method: $parent.removeItem, bindingContext: $context" />
```

In your JS:

```
viewModel: function(params) {
  this.nestedMethod = function (){
    var bindingContext = params.bindingContext;

    // @access using the following:
    // var rootVm = bindingContext.$root;
    // var currentData = bindingContext.$data;
    // var parentData = bindingContext.$parent;

    var parameter = ko.contextFor(arguments[1].target).$parent;
    params.method(parameter);
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than mucking around with contexts, just have the parent pass along a reference to itself using a closure.

HTML:

```
<!-- Note the () in the binding!!! -->
<custom-element params="click: clickHandler()"></custom-element>
```

JS:

```
var ParentView = function(message) {
    var self = this;

    self.message = message;

    self.clickHandler = function() {
        return function() {
            alert(self.message);
        }
    }
}

ko.components.register('custom-element', {
    viewModel: function(params) {
        var self = this;

        self.nestedMethod = function() {
            params.click();            
        };
    }, 
    template:  '<button data-bind="click: nestedMethod">remove item</button>'
});

ko.applyBindings(new ParentView("Hello, Knockout!"));
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/McCroskey42/99hgbm10/5/)